# Can a Star Schema Contain Outriggers?

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, snowflake-schema, star-schema

My understanding from Star Schema modelling is that dimensions must directly link to a fact table. If this is true, then a star schema can't contain Outrigger dimension table. So, is this statement true that if a schema contains Outrigger dimension, it is snowflake?

Thank you

Comment: One of the outriggers might join directly to a different fact table that is at a higher summary level

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the terms “star schema” or “snowflake” have precise definitions that are generally accepted. If you want to describe your model as a star schema, a star schema with outriggers or a snowflake then that is entirely up to you.